# Can I bind an HTML element to a js function (rather than other way around)?

Tags: javascript, html

With jQuery I can do something like this in HTML

```
<button id="click_me" type="button">Hello</button>
```

and this in js

```
$('#click_me').on('click', function() {alert('Hello')});
```

But I'd like to do the association the other way around. E.g. something like this in HTML

```
<button function="click_me" type="button">Hello</button>
```

and this in js

```
function click_me() {alert('Hello')};
```

Is there any native method of doing this, or a library/framework that can do it (I only know a little bit of jQuery)? What about passing parameters in to click_me? And what if click_me is a member of some other namespace (i.e. click_me is not a global name), how do I tell HTML about this namespace? Would I end up with as many event listeners as if I do it the jQuery way? (I'll have a lot of event listeners and would prefer event delegation if using jQuery)

Comment: <button onclick="click_me()"></button>
function click_me()
{
}

Comment: The question is what's wrong with using the `on` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use what's called "traditional event registering", which is what @user3218194 commented and Tsalikidis answered. But it's not recommended in modern web development, because it mixes the presentation and the logic of the page, and caused a lot of maintenance problems in the past (not to mention the inability to register more event listeners for the same event type).

If you really can't stand registering your listeners, use event delegation:

```
<button data-behavior="click_me" type="button"></button>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", "button[data-behavior='click_me']", function() {
    // Note: when using event delegation in jQuery, the keyword 'this' refers to the
    // target element, not the element 'on' has been called on (document in this case)
    alert("Hello, " + this.tagName); // should alert "Hello, BUTTON"
});
```

If you do this once and for all, even newly added buttons with `data-behavior="click_me"` will trigger the event listener.

This way, you've attached to your element a *semantic* attribute, which is then managed by your script.

Comment: @Tsalikidis Glad you like it :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<button onclick="javascript: click_me()"></button>

<script>
    function click_me() { }
</script>
```

- [Live preview](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CjEiu)